# How to display select box data from database in the update form, and pass it's id while submitted without any change

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I am working in a quasar (vuejs) app, where I am trying to make functional a update form. What I want is, When I submit the form without making any change to the select box, it will be submitted with it's id. But currently its just submitting the label which is a string.

my codes are :

```
  <div class="col-6">
    <q-item-label class="q-pl-sm text-weight-bold form-label">Branch <span class="text-red-6">*</span></q-item-label>
    <q-select 
      filled 
      v-model="singleData.branch" 
      dense 
      borderless 
      class="q-ma-sm"
      label="Branch" 
      emit-value 
      :options="branchList" 
      option-value="id" 
      option-label="name" 
      map-options
    />
    <span v-if="editErrors.branch" color="" class="q-pl-sm" style="color:red">{{editErrors.branch[0] }}</span>
```

Code for submitting form :

```
updateHandler(updateId) {
        this.$axios.put(API.getTarrifIteamDetails + updateId, 
        this.singleData).then(response => {
            if (response.data.code == 200) {
                this.$q.notify({
                    type: 'positive',
                    timeout: 500,
                    position: 'top',
                    message: 'Tarrif Item Updated Successfully !'
                })
                this.editErrors = []

                this.$parent.getList()
                this.$parent.closeAllModal()
            } else {
                this.$q.notify({
                    type: 'negative',
                    position: 'top',
                    timeout: 500,
                    message: 'Form submission Failed !'
                })
                this.editErrors = response.data.error
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            this.$q.notify({
                type: 'negative',
                position: 'top',
                timeout: 500,
                message: 'Form submission Failed !'
            })
            this.editErrors = error.response.data.errors
        })
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use `emit-value` you should probably use `map-options` too.

From the documentation

> map-options : Boolean
>
> Description Try to map labels of model from 'options' Array; has a
> small performance penalty; If you are using emit-value you will
> probably need to use map-options to display the label text in the
> select field rather than the value; Refer to the 'Affecting model'
> section above

Comment: still does not work

Comment: can you paste the code for form submitting?

Comment: please check bottom part of the question, I have updated with code for update form submit